# HOw to merge two tables in R according to certain condition

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, merge

Suppose I have two tables:
TABLE A

```
Name   age  Jobcode
james  24   LD:DS1423
Lily   19   LD:DS1288
Ruby   29   LD:DS1262
Nam    52   LD:DA1993
Roy    26   LD:DA1826
```

TABLE B (the `jobcode` in this table is all `LD:DSXXXX`)

```
Gender  Jobcode    
F       LD:DS1423
M       LD:DS1288
F       LD:DS1262
F       LD:DS1893
M       LD:DS1667
F       LD:DS1762
```

I wish to merge these two files according to the `jobcode` like this:

```
###desired output
Name   age  Jobcode     Gender
james  24   LD:DS1423   F
Lily   19   LD:DS1288   M
Ruby   29   LD:DS1262   F
```

So this is just a example, the real tables are bigger than these. In general, I want to create a new table with only same `jobcode` by merging table A and B. The final output should conclude only rows with matched `jobcode`.
I have tried to use

```
A <- read.table(A)
B<- read.table(B)
df1<-A[grep("LD:DS", A$Jobcode), ] # try to keep only "LD:DS" and get rid off the others
file<-merge(B,df1)
kable(head(file))
```

and my result is like:

```
Name   age  Jobcode     Gender
james  24   LD:DS1423   F
james  24   LD:DS1288   F
james  24   LD:DS1262   F
```

Besides the `jobcode`, all the other info has just been repeated same, which is so wrong from what I expected.

I also tried to use `merge` directly but I have the same result as above. Don't know why...

Comment: I get the desired output (in different row order) when I run the code above.

Comment: Same as @JonSpring. I wonder if you've got something else loaded in your environment or a package is blocking the base `merge`. Restart R & try it in a fresh session

Comment: I'm not sure if this is related to the size of data since I'm dealing with 2 tables with over 5k rows for each. But I get the wrong result with the code I posted above. @JonSpring

Comment: If you run `conflicts(detail = TRUE)` do you see a function called merge?

Comment: You get the wrong result with these sample data frames? Or you get the wrong result with the full data frames?